# Ruby idioms for grouping symbols

Tags: ruby, module, symbols

I was reading some examples on symbols in ruby, and one example was using a symbol to represent a state name, for example `:Montana`

However, coming from Java, I would typically use enums here. What I like about enums is that you can group them, so I can do something like:

enum States {
      Montana, Minnesota, ...
   }

And then in the Java code I can call

```
States.Montana
```

Is there a logical way to group related symbols in ruby? Would it make sense to create a module containing the symbols? Or is there a more idiomatic way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to use modules for this.

```
module States
    MN = "Minnesota"
    WI = "Wisconsin"
end

puts States::MN #=> "Minnesota"
```

On a side note, "symbol" in Ruby usually refers to the [Symbol class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) which is sort of like an interned string. You write a symbol like `:my_symbol`. They are often used as keys in `HashMap`s*.

*Should be `Hash` not `HashMap`.

Comment: Are you getting your languages mixed up? I think you meant to say "They are often used as keys in `Hash`s".

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array of symbols or strings:

```
states = [:Montana, :Minnesota, ...]

states.each { |s| puts s }   # print one state each line
puts *states                 # another way to do the same
```

For that example is worth to say that `puts` converts the argument(s) into string(s); so you can safely use symbols with it. I think the symbols are more useful if you don't intend display or manipulate them; else you may want to use strings.

A case where symbols are useful is for indexing a `Hash`:

```
states = { :montana => 'beautiful', :minnesota => 'wonderful', ... }
puts states[:washington]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this is to use raw symbols. Just pass the symbol for the name, use `downcase` to allow some flexibility (optional) and validate the symbol against a list of valid symbols (optional).